# Is it possible to disable mini profiler handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I want to disable profiling and also mini-profiler-resources/results, mini-profiler-resources/results-list endpoints depending on some boolean flag. I know that i can skip starting profiler for the request but still endpoints to results are available (exception is thrown but they exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I analyzed code and I can answer to my own question. Mini profiler is registered as `IRouteHandler` and `IHttpHandler`. If you'll use any method from mini profiler it will initialize this module by firing ctor of `WebRequestProfilerProvider`. So if you want to disable mini profiler and all routes (mini-profiler-resources/results, mini-profiler-resources/results-index) make sure that you don't fire any mini profile method including:

- ProfilingViewEngine registration.
- ProfilingActionFilter (Custom profiler filter for MVC).
- Include method in view for scripts and styles.
- MiniProfiler.Start and .Stop methods.